# Why does the break statement fail to break out of the while loop?

Tags: while-loop, d

Here is an D exercise:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{

    int[] narray;
    while(true) {
        writeln("Enter your numbers: ");
        int tmp;
        readf(" %s", &tmp);
        if(tmp == -1) {
            writeln("It's -1, finish reading numbers.");
            break;
        }
        else {
            writeln("Storing ", tmp, " to array.");
            narray ~= tmp;
            printArray(narray);
        }
    }

    int[] narrayOdd;
    int[] narrayEven;
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < narray.length) {
        if((counter % 2) == 0) {
            narrayEven ~= narray[counter];
        }
        else {
            narrayOdd ~= narray[counter];
        }
    }

    narrayOdd.sort;
    narrayEven.sort;
    writeln("Your numbers in odd positions sorted: ");
    printArray(narrayOdd);
    writeln("Your numbers in even positions sorted: ");
    printArray(narrayEven);

}

void printArray(int[] x) {
    int counter;
    while(counter < x.length) {
        write(x[counter], " ");
        counter++;
    }
    write("\n");
}
```

I meant to break out of the while loop when the user inputs -1, but it refuses to do so. Anything wrong?

I tried both dmd and ldc2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **does** break out of the while loop when you input -1, and then proceeds to get stuck in the next while loop. You are checking `while(counter < narray.length)` but never incrementing counter.
Try:

```
while(counter < narray.length) {
    if((counter % 2) == 0) {
        narrayEven ~= narray[counter++];
    }
    else {
        narrayOdd ~= narray[counter++];
    }
}
```

or:

```
foreach(counter , value ; narray) {
   if((counter % 2) == 0) {
       narrayEven ~= value;
   }
   else {
       narrayOdd ~= value;
   }
}
```

in the second form, the `foreach` loop creates two temporary variables. `counter` refers to the index of each element and is automatically incremented, and `value` refers to the value at that index.

If you're not familiar with `foreach`, look [here](http://dlang.org/statement.html#ForeachStatement). `foreach` is generally preferable to `while` for iterating over a collection unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.